# How to Audit/log file access events on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, mdm

I want to keep track of my files that where it has been stored and to which of the apps that file is shared. For example,
I downloaded a file on my app A, now I have shared it with app B then app B shared it with app C. Is it possible that I can trace out that at which places this particular file exists?

Did Apple MDM have any feature like that? Main aim is (DLP) Data Loss Preventions.

Or any solution for that on jailbreak devices?

Comment: Your application's data is confined to its sandbox. You can keep track of where the file's going when distributing it with a share sheet. But once that file leaves your application, you're not going to be able to find out where it goes in the future if it's shared by the original file recipient.

Comment: @Dare is there any API apple provide for supervised devices?